File uploads to SFTP storage but not retrieved
I am trying to configure SFTP storage for uploading of image and pdf files.
My configuration for filesystems.php
'default' => 'sftp-storage',
'disks' => [
     'sftp-storage' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => env('GN_HOST'),
        'port' => env('GN_PORT'),
        'username' => env('GN_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('GN_PASSWORD'),
        'root' => env('GN_DIR_PATH'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
] 

File uploads when uploading from system.
Output of ls -l of sftp storage directory
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 usertwo usertwo  111718 Dec  5 10:46 ggve3PVyVwb1ZzwrzwKWQUzHlNPKDhdE9iJknM1I.png
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 usertwo usertwo 1246354 Dec  5 11:34 Qqr3hbf7Bc9tg2hcYjeZt4YyOAN1XdQsoU3Bh2dn.png

But when the system retrieves the files, it tries to retrieve from public folder (the file present in public folder is retrieved correctly)
Code for file retrieval
public function show(int $reg_id, $document_name, int $id)
{
    $document_types = DocumentMaster::pluck('document_name')->toArray();

    /*Check if the document requested is a valid document from the list of DocumentMaster stored in database. If not display invalid document type error*/
    if (!in_array($document_name, $document_types)) {
         return response()->json("Document type invalid", 404);
    }
    $document_master_id = DocumentMaster::where('document_name', $document_name)->first()->id;
    $documents = Documents::where('document_master_id', $document_master_id)
                    ->where('reg_id', $reg_id)
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->get();

    if ($documents !=null  && count($documents)) {
        return response()->json(['data'=>$documents], 200);
    }
    else {
        $response = ['message' => 'The '.$document_name.' document does not exist for reg_id '.$reg_id];
        return response()->json($response, 404);
    }
    
}

And for the files uploaded to sftp storage, it shows 404 not found.
What I might be doing wrong here?
Edit:
The 404 status
The response section is empty


"when the system retrieves the files" - Please add the actual code responsible for retrieving the file

@DarkBee, I have added the code for retrieving the file and data.

Your code has multiple 404 responses, which one is triggering? Is it the "Document type is invalid" one or the "The '.$document_name.' document does not exist for reg_id '.$reg_id"  one?

@DarkBee The response section is blank. I have attached the picture of response in the question.

So what's the actual URL to the file? As seen in the screenshot you a have an extra / to start with, http://www.example.com//img/filename.jpg  - Where are you outputting this file?

The extra slash do not affect the file retrieval. One file is retrieved from local public with double / and it retrieves properly. Though I have changed the default of the filesystems.php, still it retrieves files from local public directory

Can you share the upload code and Download code

I think issue is that system is not considering from where it need to take file. You can check that file exist on the storage by doing something like this:
$filePath = $document->file_path; // or your column name

    if (Storage::disk('sftp-storage')->exists($filePath)) {
        return response()->json(['data' => $document], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'File not found on storage'], 404);

